# How to order by getting data with Id to firestore in python

Tags: python, json, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How to order by Firestore get data with id in Python?

`list(firestoreDb.collection(u'Messages').get())`

this code is getting all data. How to use `orderBy()` in python, I can't find .`get().orderBy()`

I use python 3.11 with vscode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not:

```
get().orderBy()
```

But:

```
list(firestoreDb.collection(u'Messages').order_by("field_name").get())
//
```

You have to call `.order_by()` on a collection reference in order to create a query. Please check below the docs:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data